# How do I override xhr-src?

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest, xss

I created a userscript for myself which is active on all webpages i visit. It sends data to my debugger/app via jquery's post ($.post).

I notice one site not allowing me to send data even though it worked before and after a quick look it appears there is some kind of error via `xhr-src`. It appears the response headers has a 'X-Content-Security-Policy' which list a bunch of sites (google being one). So when i try to do a post to localhost:myport/ it violates the rule thus doesn't post.

What can I do to get this working again? I can't exactly edit the headers (unless i write my own http proxy?) would i be able to create an iframe using localhost:1234/workaround and post via that? But the issue is i still dont know if thats a violation or how to give it data.

Comment: Have you looked at the **Related** questions referring to Cross-site XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes but they seem to be more of how to keep XMLHttpRequest from working, which browser supports it (old question) and differences XMLHttpRequest has on regular request. None  of them are even close to how do i get XMLHttpRequest to work

Comment: The general answer is that you either use JSONP if the site supports it, or you have to use a proxy.

Comment: @Barmar: I just looked it up. It appears to be able to pull data? and bot post it?